# Print a list in HTML file using Django

Tags: python, html, django

I want to print a list called formulario and I want to paste them into a html file using Django template language, although I'm not able to display that information in `<li>` tag. Is there sth am I missing?

views.py

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
import pandas as pd

formulario = ["Hola", "Hi"]

def formulario(request):
        return render (request, "formulario/formulario.html",{
            "formulario":formulario
        })
```

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Formulario !</h1>

    <ul>
        {% for formulario in formulario %}
            <li>{formulario}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    
    path("index.html",views.index, name="index"),
    path("financierofinanciamiento.html",views.financiamiento, name="financiamiento"),
    path("financierobeneficio.html",views.beneficio, name="beneficio"),
    path("tecnicoinfra.html",views.infra, name="infra"),
    path("tecnicoequipo.html",views.equipo, name="equipo"),
    path("tecnicoherramientas.html",views.herramientas, name="herramientas"),
    path("tecnicomateriaprima.html",views.materiaprima, name="materiaprima"),
    path("formulario.html",views.formulario, name="formulario"),  
]
```

Comment: It has to be `<li>{{ formulario }}</li>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  {% for item  in formulario %}
        <li>{{ item }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I don't know what you did but it works, for some reason when I put instead of "item" formulario" it doesn't work. Don't know why, but at least your solution works, Thanks !

Comment: The item name cant have the same name as the list.

Comment: Great info ! Thanks !